# PowerShell parse eml file without unzip

Tags: powershell, stream, adodb, eml

Currently I have a zip file containing some eml files, I need to parse and get all the emails in the From & To parts of each one of the eml files without unzipping the zip folder.

In order to read the eml files in my zip I'm using this code:

```
# Open outer ZIP as an archive
$zipFileContent = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($file.FullName)
$emlEntries = $zipFileContent.Entries
$emlEntries | ForEach-Object {
     # Here I need to parse each eml file without unzipping them, to do so I'm trying this

     # Instantiate new ADODB Stream object
     $adoStream = New-Object -ComObject 'ADODB.Stream'    
     # Open stream
     $adoStream.Open()    
     # Load file
     $adoStream.LoadFromFile($_)    
     # Instantiate new CDO Message Object
     $cdoMessageObject = New-Object -ComObject 'CDO.Message'
     # Open object and pass stream
     $cdoMessageObject.DataSource.OpenObject($adoStream, '_Stream')
}
```

I'm getting an error, as the method LoadFromFile expects to have a "local" file instead of a System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream, could you please help me in order to achieve my goal please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems like the method [only supports an actual path be it absolute or UNC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/loadfromfile-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver16#parameters) as argument. It will not work with a stream.

Comment: From what I read yes, it accepts only real path, but the code was just to illustrate the current situation. I need some advice or alternative to try to move forward

Comment: What I meant is that this comobject doesn't support what you want to do, it seems you will need to extract the contents before processing them or, if for some reason, you could extract entry by entry and removing entry by entry

Comment: If performance is your concern, you may create a temporary file with `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` and `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` flags. This creates a file that isn't physically stored on disk, but backed by system memory (if sufficient). There isn't a PowerShell or .NET function that is able to create a file with these flags, but you could P/Invoke the native `CreateFile` function.

Comment: Regardless the code that I'm showing, and the CreateFile function, there is no other way to read a Stream containing an eml file and extract the attributes From and To?